# How can I open a CSV file in iPython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, ipython, spyder

I'm a newbie to Python. I downloaded a csv file to use. I use the Anaconda package in Python 2.7 on Windows 8.1.  I can open and read the file in Spyder perfectly, but when I try to open it in the iPython shell, i get the following error message:

```
 [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python stuff/Data.csv
```

My code -

```
DSI_data = open('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python stuff/Data.csv')

DSI_reader = (pd.read_csv(DSI_data), ',')

print DSI_reader
```

Output :

---

```
 IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-2-14a014f3c776> in <module>()

       1 
 ----> 2 DSI_data = open(''C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python stuff/Data.csv')
       3 
       4 DSI_reader = (pd.read_csv(DSI_data), ',')
       5 

 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python stuff/Data.csv'
```

I would like to open this file in Spyder and not being found by iPython. Also, I need to know how to open this iniPython

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. In other words, the actual code you ran

Comment: The error message means the location from which you are trying to open the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Why are there two opening quotes in the error message?

Comment: The error is pretty descriptive, and tells you that there is no file, with that name, at that location. Are you sure that `Data.csv` exists in that directory? I haven't used Windows in a while, but don't Windows paths use `\\` ("back-slashes")?

Comment: If it didn't, how is Spyder able to assess the file? Curious , I'm still new to Python.

Comment: can you try to copy the data.csv file to c:\ ? and then try to open it using: open('c:\data.csv')?  (I suggest it - to isolate the problem - e.g. no spaces in the folder-name)

Comment: try using `C://Users//User//Desktop//Python stuff//Data.csv`

Comment: Have you tried reading it as raw string like `df=pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python stuff/Data.csv')`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is one of finding and properly naming the file.  I would suggest using

```
%pwd
```

to find out what the current directory is.

```
%ls
```

to see what is in that directory

and

```
%cd ...
```

to change to the right subdirectory.

Also use the tab complete.

```
f = open('Da<tab>
```

will give you list of files that start with `Da`, assuming you are in the right directory.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of working with python in windows but Here I am giving the solution to the problem opening the csv file in ipython notebook.

Before using this code please check the path of the csv file.

**Loading csv file in ipython notebook**

```
import pandas as pd
DSI_data_path = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python stuff/Data.csv"
DSI_data = pd.read_csv(DSI_data_path)
print DSI_data
```

Answer (score 0):

try to save the csv file inside a folder in drive C

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('qwa.csv', encoding='cp1252')  
print(df.head())
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.